# Identify Circles

Tags: c++, c, opencv

The code given below is supposed to identify circles in a video feed. The for loop is not executing. Why is it so?

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CvCapture* capture=0;
    capture=cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    if(!capture)
    {
        printf("Capture failure\n");
        return -1;
    }
    IplImage* frame;
    while(true)
    {
        frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if(!frame) break;
        Mat src(frame);
        IplImage* framegray=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,3);
        Mat srcgray(framegray);
        cvtColor(src,srcgray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(srcgray,srcgray,Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
        vector<Vec3f> circles;

        HoughCircles( srcgray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, srcgray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
        {
            Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
            int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
            circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0 );
        }
        namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );
        int c=cvWaitKey(10);
        if(char(c)==27)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The sample imaged used to test the program when not using the camera are given below:|
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, probably because it didn't find circles? How did you test? Do you have example input? What is it with `srcgray.rows/8`?

Comment: @ypnos The minimum distance between detected circles, in the sample program its rows/8 thus I am using the same values. Is it incorrect?

Comment: Is the for loop entered at all? What's the value of circles.size() there?

Comment: I suspect `if(!frame) break;` or an exception somewhere.

Comment: @ChristianSeverin not entered at all.

Comment: @Marian I checked and its not the reason. The program is running, its not entering the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### edit

i was wrong. cv::houghCircles doesnt require edges as input. all you need are good parameters. i have checked with opencv implemenation and it's already doing sobel internally. thanks @micka for correction

---

hough requires edges as input. i have slightly modified your program and verified that it's working by pointing the webcam to monitor.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CvCapture* capture=0;
    capture=cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    if(!capture)
    {
        printf("Capture failure\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int dp=1,mindist=100,param1=300,param2=60,minradius=0,maxradius=0;
    cv::namedWindow("ctrl");
    cv::createTrackbar( "dp", "ctrl", &dp, 50);
    cv::createTrackbar( "mindist", "ctrl", &mindist, 1000);
    cv::createTrackbar( "param1", "ctrl", &param1, 1000);
    cv::createTrackbar( "param2", "ctrl", &param2, 1000);
    cv::createTrackbar( "minradius", "ctrl", &minradius, 1000);
    cv::createTrackbar( "maxradius", "ctrl", &maxradius, 1000);
    IplImage* frame;
    while(true)
    {
        frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if(!frame) break;
        Mat src(frame);
        IplImage* framegray=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,3);
        Mat srcgray(framegray);
        cvtColor(src,srcgray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        vector<Vec3f> circles;

        HoughCircles( srcgray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp,mindist, param1, param2, minradius, maxradius );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
        {
            Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
            int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
            circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0 );
        }
        namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );
        cvReleaseImage(&framegray);
        int c=cvWaitKey(1);
        if(char(c)==27)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cv::HoughCircles doesn't require edges as input, works perfectly for me on filled circle images without gradient/edge extraction.

Comment: What does the Sobel operator do?

Comment: Sobel computes directed derivatives and it is used to compute the gradient magnitude which is used as edge information. Here is an example: http://www.viznet.ac.uk/files/PyGPULena.jpg

Comment: @Micka,hmm..i guess it requires circles to be brighter than it's local background, does it still work if you invert it.

Comment: yes, it still works on inverted image.
I guess maybe cv::HoughCircles internally uses some edge extraction mechanism (as this is the precomputation step of a Hough-Transformation in most cases), which will probably be a Sobel operator. So extracting edges before calling cv::HoughCircles might lead to increased execution times and maybe wrong results.

Comment: the implementation details of cv::HoughCircles is opaque to me and personally i find the matlab version found @mathworks perform better than opencv implementation. assuming that you are indeed right,doing edges by oneself at least have the advantage of being able to remove irrelevant data such as by band-pass filtering the sobel image

Comment: unfortunately `http://docs.opencv.org/` isn't online at the moment, so I can't say what kind of other methods can be used instead of `CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT`. But first precomputation of your own gradient and then let HoughCircles compute the gradient again (on the precomputed gradient) is definitely not what you want to do in all cases!

Answer (score 1):

Trying your code it works with your test images. I changed the code to consistent c++ openCV syntax not using IplImage anymore.

```
void identifyCircles()
{

    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("identifyCircles2.png");

    cv::Mat srcgray;
    cv::cvtColor(src,srcgray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::GaussianBlur(srcgray,srcgray,Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;

    cv::HoughCircles( srcgray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, srcgray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
        cv::Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        circle( src, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0 );
    }
    cv::namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );
    cv::imwrite("houghCirclesIdentified.png",src);
    cv::waitKey(-1);

}
```

gives me outputs:

[image]

[image]

so your problem might be the video stream input, that the circles there might not be "good" enough. Or your images aren't streamed correctly (are the images displayed?!?).

If the `for loop` isn't entered, `circles.size() is <= 0` so you might want to add a `std::cout << "circles found in this image: " << circles.size() << std::endl` or a `if(circles.size() == 0) std::cout << "no circles found" << std::endl` for debugging.

Comment: For static images it is working. Originally I had the same thing. It should also work in real time.

Comment: can you provide a sample camera image (with a not identified circle in it) or a short captured video, please?